# How to translate this query from SQL(mysql) to Eloquent(Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In writing a custom query that returns users with their posts grouped and a count with the total posts made by them

**query in SQL**

```
SELECT users.nameUser, COUNT(posts.namePost) AS Total, GROUP_CONCAT(posts.namePost) AS List
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
GROUP BY users.nameUser;
+----------+-------+-----------------------+
| nameUser | Total | List                  |
+----------+-------+-----------------------+
| alfa     |     2 | PHP 7,Aire comprimido |
| beta     |     2 | HTML 5,MySQL 8        |
+----------+-------+-----------------------+
```

The question is, how can build this query with Eloquent Laravel or even with it query Builder?

Comment: check this url please: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder

Answer (score 1):

This is only a way to do it, using Eloquent ORM and for certain tasks using Fluent

```
$data = User::select('users.nameUser')
           ->selectRaw('COUNT(posts.namePost) AS Total')
           ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(posts.namePost) AS List')
           ->join('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
           ->groupBy('users.nameUser')
           ->get();
```

Useful stuff

1. You can use `selectRaw()` method instead of `DB::raw()` method
2. I use the `User` model to avoid include more query builder code
3. I use `groupBy()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can pass raw query string as DB statement:

```
$data = DB::statement('
    SELECT users.nameUser, COUNT(posts.namePost) AS Total, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(posts.namePost) AS List
    FROM users
    JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
    GROUP BY users.nameUser
')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have set User and Post models with relation between?

Comment: yeah I was forgotten it, both tables have a relationship

Comment: I wondered could you use something like `User::with('posts')->all()` and then use some of helper functions available to filter or sort result.